# Linux: Whether calling wait() from one thread will cause all other threads also to go to sleep?

Tags: c, linux

"The wait() system call suspends execution of the current process until one of its children terminates" . Waitpid also is similar.

My Question is whether calling wait() from one thread will cause all other threads (in the same process) also to go to sleep ? Do the behavior is same for detached threads also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a bug in the manual. `wait` suspends the calling thread, not the process. There is absolutely no way to suspend the whole process short of sending it `SIGSTOP` or manually suspending each thread one at a time.

Comment: Is this specific to Linux ? Since Linux is having separate kernel process for each thread.

Comment: Some context: Linux 2.4 didn't have true POSIX threads.  Each thread was treated as a different process.  This was changed for Linux 2.6, which has full POSIX threading.  I guess some manual pages weren't updated.

Comment: But even in 2.4 it was wrong; because threads behaved like processes, of course only one thread would be suspended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, calling wait from any thread will cause all threads which are associated with that process to halt.

But don't hold me to that. Best thing to do would be to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Should only stop the current thread.  If you want to make people ill when they look at your code and cause yourself a lot of problems you can use this for jury rigged thread synchronization.  I wouldn't reccommend it though.